# How to change the value of a line in a file inside a loop without adding new lines with Python?

Tags: python, json

I know that the title may not be very clear so here's my problem below:
I'm pretty new to Python, I have a yaml file that contains many occurrence of this bloc of code:

```
x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
      responses:
        default:
          statusCode: "200"
      uri: addProfile_uri
      passthroughBehavior: when_no_match
      httpMethod: POST
      cacheNamespace: roq9wj
      cacheKeyParameters:
      - method.request.path.proxy
      type: aws_proxy

x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
      responses:
        default:
          statusCode: "200"
      uri: deleteProfile_uri
      passthroughBehavior: when_no_match
      httpMethod: POST
      cacheNamespace: roq9wj
      cacheKeyParameters:
      - method.request.path.proxy
      type: aws_proxy
```

And a json file that contains this:

```
[
  {
    "function_variable_uri_name": "addProfile_uri",
    "uri": "arn:aws:apigateway:XXXXXX"
  },
  {
    "function_variable_uri_name": "deleteProfile_uri",
    "uri": "arn:aws:apigateway:XXXXXX"
  },
  {
    "function_variable_uri_name": "getAllProfile_uri",
    "uri": "arn:aws:apigateway:XXXXXX"
  },
  {
    "function_variable_uri_name": "getProfile_uri",
    "uri": "arn:aws:apigateway:XXXXXX"
  },
  {
    "function_variable_uri_name": "updateProfile_uri",
    "uri": "arn:aws:apigateway:XXXXXX"
  }
]
```

So in my Python code, I've tried to loop inside the JSON file, extract both `uri` and `function_variable_uri_name` values. The idea was to loop inside the yaml file and search for every occurrence of `function_variable_uri_name` (example: `deleteProfile_uri`) and change it with the `uri` value `arn:aws:apigateway:XXXXXX`.

```
import json

flambda = open('uri_var.json')
lambda_inputs = json.load(flambda)

fout = open("profile_modif.yaml", "wt")

with open('profile.yaml', 'r+') as file:
    for each in lambda_inputs:
        variable_uri_name = each['function_variable_uri_name']
        uri = each['uri']
        for line in file:
            fout.write(line.replace(variable_uri_name, uri))
                
file.close()
```

My Python code above is changing only the value of the first occurrence of `variable_uri_name` inside YAML which is `addProfile_uri` to the value of `uri` and not changing the `deleteProfile_uri`, and I need the for-loop inside my JSON file because I have many inputs to be treated.

Update: Here is a simple print for both values of `function_variable_uri_name` and `uri` from my json file:

```
addProfile_uri
arn:aws:apigateway:XXXXXX
deleteProfile_uri
arn:aws:apigateway:XXXXXX
getAllProfile_uri
arn:aws:apigateway:XXXXXX
getProfile_uri
arn:aws:apigateway:XXXXXX
updateProfile_uri
arn:aws:apigateway:XXXXXX
```

Any solutions, please? Thank you all in advance.

Comment: I think you should clean up your json file first to have comfortable flawless iteration. Actually your data are list with nested curly braces items. then readlines() method could do the job.

Comment: @Cyber-Tech Thank you for your response but sorry I didn't get your point. Actually I'm getting all the values that I need from my json file using: for each in lambda_inputs. I mean, I don't really get what is exactly the problem with the json file.

Comment: I see 2 vertical points before the last line in json, what is their function?

Comment: @Cyber-Tech I'm sorry I didn't pay attention to that, it's just a typo. I've updated it, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change how you're thinking about the work.  You want to work once on each line, and perform multiple check and replace operations on each line.  In other words, you want to iterate on the file first, then iterate on the replacement variables in a nested operation on the file operation:

```py
import json

with open('uri_var.json') as flambda:
    lambda_inputs = json.load(flambda)

with open("profile_modif.yaml", "wt") as fout:
    with open('profile.yaml', 'r+') as file:
        for line in file:
            for item in lambda_inputs:
                line = line.replace(item['function_variable_uri_name'], item['uri'])
            fout.write(line)
```